# Showing equivalence of integrals using Stokes' theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\alpha: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth immersion. Let $\Gamma: D^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth map that restricts to $\alpha$ on the boundary. After messing around a bit with Mathematica, I'm convinced that

$$\int_{D^2} \Gamma^*\,dx_1 \wedge dx_2 = \int_\alpha x_1\,dx_2.$$

How do I see this? I know we want to use Stokes' theorem somehow, could anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\int_{D^2}\Gamma^*(dx_1\wedge dx_2) &= \int_{D^2}\Gamma^*(d(x_1 dx_2))\\ 
&= \int_{D^2}d(\Gamma^*(x_1dx_2))\\ 
&= \int_{\partial D^2}\Gamma^*(x_1dx_2)\\ 
&= \int_{S^1}\Gamma^*(x_1dx_2)\\ 
&= \int_{S^1}\alpha^*(x_1dx_2).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely Stokes's Theorem. $d(x_1\,dx_2) = dx_1\wedge dx_2$ and $d(\Gamma^*\phi) = \Gamma^*(d\phi)$ for any form $\phi$, so
$$\int_{D^2} \Gamma^* d(x_1\,dx_2) = \int_{D^2} d\big(\Gamma^*(x_1\,dx_2)\big) = \int_{\partial D^2}\Gamma^*(x_1\,dx_2) = \int_{S^1} \alpha^*(x_1\,dx_2),$$
as required.

Comment: Beat me to it. Do you know what the OP means by $\int_{\alpha}x_1dx_2$?

Comment: @MichaelA: Sure, that's somewhat standard notation for integrating over a (smooth) singular chain.